# Reducing variance in linear regression

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

While reading The Elements of Statistical Learning the author states that by shriking the coefficients of a liinear regression you raise the bias while lowering the variance and thus, sometimes, reducing the error of the prediction. But I don't quite get why that necessarily happens, I understand the bias variance tradeoff but can't grasp the direct relationship of the parameters of the model to these actual statistics.

Comment: *sometimes* and *necessarily* are different words.  Suppose you are trying to model $Z$ using data on $X$ and $Y$ which happen to be highly correlated and often almost equal: with ordinary linear regression you might end up with a model which gives a high positive coefficient to $X$ and a high negative coefficient to $Y$, which usually offset each other and the model is really looking at $X-Y$.  But for a point where $X$ and $Y$ are not almost equal, this could lead to an implausibly large prediction for $Z$ and a huge squared error: shrinking the coefficients reduces the possibility of this

Comment: ... but at a cost of losing some of the benefits of ordinary linear regression, such as no bias.  The question is whether this price is worth paying in terms of total error: sometimes it can be.

Comment: Actually my questions is in relation on how the variance of the coefficients specifically affect the model's variance, and thus the mean squared error.